# VBA macro for copying conditional data to specific cells

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new to programming in VBA and I'm looking To take data from different worksheets that matches a condition.  Then copy and paste from one specific cell to another specific cell 7 times. The code I have doesn't work and I'm looking to improve it. As I run the code I get flagged for Run time error '1004' Method 'Range of object '_Worksheet' failed at the beginning of the IF statement.

```
 Sub CopyValues()

 'Declare variables
 'Declare sheet variables
 Dim Sourcews As Worksheet
 Dim Pastews As Worksheet

 'Declare counter variables
 Dim i As Integer
 Dim n As Integer
 Dim lastrow As Long

 Set Sourcews = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Source")
 Set Pastews = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Paste")

  lastrow = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

 For i = 3 To lastrow

 If Sourcews.Range(i, "AA").Value = "Needed Value" Then

    Pastews.Cells("C:18").Paste
    Pastews.Cells("D:18").Paste
    Pastews.Cells("E:18").Paste
    Pastews.Cells("F:18").Paste
    Pastews.Cells("G:18").Paste
    Pastews.Cells("H:18").Paste



End If

Next
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is.  Does the code you posted work properly?

Comment: No I'm looking to improve it

Comment: What is the result of the code currently?

Comment: Probably the error is here `Pastews.Cells("H:18").Paste` Should it be  `Pastews.Range("H18").Paste`? (Have not checked) And all values should be like this.

Comment: If it works and you are looking to make it better then check out [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I'm getting flagged with  "1004" error at the beginning of the IF statement

Comment: Your syntax is confused, as pointed out by TBlock in his answer. Also you are pasting but not copying first. And paste is a method of the sheet object, not range object. Explain your end objective in plain English.

Comment: To take data from different worksheets that matches a condition.  Then copy and paste from one specific cell to another specific cell 7 times.

Answer (score 2):

Try this. I'm assuming you want to paste into row 18 and then 19 etc, and not 18 repeatedly!

```
Sub CopyValues()

'Declare variables
'Declare sheet variables
Dim Sourcews As Worksheet
Dim Pastews As Worksheet

'Declare counter variables
Dim i As Long
Dim n As Long
Dim lastrow As Long

Set Sourcews = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Source")
Set Pastews = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Paste")

lastrow = Sourcews.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
n = 18

For i = 3 To lastrow
    If Sourcews.Cells(i, "AA").Value = "Needed Value" Then
        Sourcews.Cells(i, "AA").Copy Pastews.Cells(n, "C").Resize(, 6)
        n = n + 1
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Well I just want row 18 and copy across the columns

Comment: Have you tried the code? Let me know how you get on. I don't understand what you want to happen the second time the value is found.

Comment: There is no run time error but its not running. How come?

Comment: Is "Needed Value" or whatever actually in column AA? Check the value of `lastrow` - step through your code using F8.

Comment: Yes the value that I'm checking against is in AA.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `.Cells("C:18")` use `.Range("C18")`. For questions like this, you can also try recording a macro and learning code from what Excel tells you.

Answer (score 0):

The `If` should be like this:

`If Sourcews.Range("AA"&i).Value = "Needed Value" Then`

Then in the `Pastews.Cells`, it should be refered to the Worksheet like this:

```
pastews.Range("A18").Copy Destination:=pastews.Range("H18")
```

or

```
pastews.Cells(18,1).Copy Destination:=pastews.Cells(18,8)
```

Here is the **MSDN** article about ranges in VBA - it's worth reading - 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-object-excel

Comment: That will error because Paste is a method of the Sheet object, not the Range object (I'm sure you know this but just missed it on this occasion).

Answer (score 0):

Aside from some syntax errors that others have discussed, you haven't specified what is bieng copied before you try to use the `.paste` method.  I would just avoid the copy and paste methods (they are inefficient) and set the cells equal to the value of the range in the `if` statement like so:

```
Sub CopyValues()

 'Declare variables
 'Declare sheet variables
 Dim Sourcews As Worksheet
 Dim Pastews As Worksheet

 'Declare counter variables
 Dim i As Integer
 Dim n As Integer
 Dim lastrow As Long

 Set Sourcews = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1")
 Set Pastews = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet2")

  lastrow = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

 For i = 3 To lastrow

If Sourcews.Range("AA" & i).Value = "Needed Value" Then

    Pastews.Range("C18") = Sourcews.Range("AA" & i).Value
    Pastews.Range("D18") = Sourcews.Range("AA" & i).Value
    Pastews.Range("E18") = Sourcews.Range("AA" & i).Value
    Pastews.Range("F18") = Sourcews.Range("AA" & i).Value
    Pastews.Range("G18") = Sourcews.Range("AA" & i).Value



End If

Next

End Sub
```

Or you could set the value as a variable for cleaner looking code, like this:

```
Sub CopyValues()

 'Declare variables
 'Declare sheet variables
 Dim Sourcews As Worksheet
 Dim Pastews As Worksheet

 'Declare counter variables
 Dim i As Integer
 Dim n As Integer
 Dim lastrow As Long
 Dim x As String

 Set Sourcews = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1")
 Set Pastews = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet2")

  lastrow = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

 For i = 3 To lastrow

If Sourcews.Range("AA" & i).Value = "Needed Value" Then

    x = Sourcews.Range("AA" & i).Value
    Pastews.Range("C18") = x
    Pastews.Range("D18") = x
    Pastews.Range("E18") = x
    Pastews.Range("F18") = x
    Pastews.Range("G18") = x



End If

Next

End Sub
```

Or, to make the code even more concise, you can combine the range that is receiving the copied value as `Pastews.Range("C18:G18") = x` like this:

```
Sub CopyValues()

 'Declare variables
 'Declare sheet variables
 Dim Sourcews As Worksheet
 Dim Pastews As Worksheet

 'Declare counter variables
 Dim i As Integer
 Dim n As Integer
 Dim lastrow As Long
 Dim x As String

 Set Sourcews = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1")
 Set Pastews = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet2")

  lastrow = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

 For i = 3 To lastrow

If Sourcews.Range("AA" & i).Value = "Needed Value" Then

    x = Sourcews.Range("AA" & i).Value
    Pastews.Range("C18:G18") = x

End If

Next

End Sub
```

I know I posted a lot, but I wanted to show you a progression of how your could can be more concise and efficient.  I hope it helps.

Comment: Hey Jarom  I tired running the first block of code but nothing is happening. not even a run time error

Comment: did you change the name of the sheets from `sheet1` and `sheet2` back to `source` and `paste`?  I changed the names to debug on my machine.  I edited the answer, but I forgot on my original post to switch them back.

Comment: Source is where the data is, paste is where I'm trying to get it to

Comment: If it is not that the sheet names are incorrect (which was my mistake) then it probably has something to do with the `for loop` not having the correct counters.  Do you know how to debug in the VBA environment?

Comment: No problem! In the editor where you see your code you can execute the code line by line by hitting the F8 key.  This is really important to be able to see what your code is doing.  So go into the editor, click anywhere inside your code and start pressing F8.  The editor will highlight the line it will execute next in yellow.  F8 thru the lines until you get the yellow line on the `for` statment.  Then hover your mouse over the `lastrow` variable to see the value of the variable. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Ok thank you, this help a lot. Is there a reason why the code doesn't populate the cells?  There is no run time error.

Comment: When you F8 through the code, what does it do when you are going thru the loop?

Comment: As I press F8 , the highlight will keep looping between the IF and Next.

Comment: So it looks like it is looping correctly.  So the problem must be in this portion `Pastews.Range("C18") = Sourcews.Range("AA" & i).Value` Put this code temporarily right after the `if` statement.  `Sourcews.Range("AA" & i).Select` After you F8 to the line below this code.  Go to excel and see what cell is selected.  This can give us an idea as to what value the code is grabbing.

Comment: Nothing is happening, Sorry I didn't make it clearer but it goes from the If statement, to the END IF and then Next and back to the beginning, Meanwhile it skips the logic statements inbetween

Comment: I feel really silly.  I had it referencing the wrong column however I need it to take the data in Cell "A" when the data in cell "AD" matches 7 times

Comment: No problem.  This is what debugging is all about.  You can just change the references for the if statement and the values to do that.  Like this:  `If Sourcews.Range("AD" & i).Value = "Needed Value" Then

    Pastews.Range("C18") = Sourcews.Range("A" & i).Value`

Comment: Ok I did that and it writes the same value over the 7 cells, when I need it to differentiate the next cell that has the same condition

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand exactly, but is sounds like you might need a nested loop.  Or a loop inside of a loop.  The outer loop to check the condition and an inner loop to iterate through the 7 cells you are talking about.

Comment: Ok, I know there is data points that exist 7 times in column "AD". But I want the value inside of cell "A" that is checked against cell "AD" to be written in a different worksheet in one row "C18:I18", they each have a particular value that I want captured

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm following you in the comments.  Maybe you should post another question with the progress you've made so that we can see the code that you are working with now.  Sorry.  I hope that I was a significant help to you.

Comment: If I answered the question to this post you can accept the answer so other users can know that this was helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

I was working through the duplicate question for this and provided this answer:

Try:

```
Sub CopyValues()

'Declare counter variables
Dim i As Integer, j as Integer, lastrow As Long
'Declare variables
Dim Sourcedataws As Worksheet, WStotransfer As Worksheet
'Declare sheet variables
Set Sourcedataws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Source Data")
Set WStotransferws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("WStotransfer")

lastrow = Sourcedataws.Cells(Sourcedataws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

WStotransferws.Range("C18:I18").ClearContents

For i = 2 To lastrow
If WStotransferws.Range("I18").Value="" Then
    If Sourcedataws.Range("AA" & i).Value = "Condition" Then
        Sourcedataws.Range("A"&i).Copy 
        j=WStotransferws.Cells(18, WStotransferws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        WStotransferws.Cells(18,j+1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End If
    Else
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Other post found: [VBA Need a Nested Loop to shift columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45445207/vba-need-a-nested-loop-to-shift-columns/45445502?noredirect=1#comment77855097_45445502)

There's a long conversation with the poster about details that were not in the post.