# VBA Need a Nested Loop to shift columns

Tags: vba, excel

Not very experienced with coding VBA, but I would appreciate any help this matter.  The code below runs fine; however logically, I feel like it could be written better. Anyone have suggestions?

```
Sub CopyValues()

  'Declare variables
   Dim Sourcedataws As Worksheet
   Dim WStotransfer As Worksheet

  'Declare counter variables
   Dim i As Integer
   Dim lastrow As Long

  'Declare sheet variables
   Set Sourcedataws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Source Data")
   Set WStotransferws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("WStotransfer")

    lastrow = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

  For i = 2 To lastrow

If Sourcedataws.Range("AA" & i).Value = "Condition" Then

    WStotransferws.Range("C18") = Sourcedataws.Range("A" & i).Value
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    WStotransferws.Range("D18") = Sourcedataws.Range("A" & i).Value
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    WStotransferws.Range("E18") = Sourcedataws.Range("A" & i).Value
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    WStotransferws.Range("F18") = Sourcedataws.Range("A" & i).Value
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    WStotransferws.Range("G18") = Sourcedataws.Range("A" & i).Value
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    WStotransferws.Range("H18") = Sourcedataws.Range("A" & i).Value
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    WStotransferws.Range("I18") = Sourcedataws.Range("A" & i).Value



End If

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not sure I fully get your question about the script. Could you put up some sample data and sample output for what the script should do?

Comment: I don't know how to record that

Comment: This looks the same as your other question.

Comment: Pull up your sample data, and use the snipping tool on your computer to get a screenshot and paste it into your post. Do the same for the desired output. (Assuming you use Windows)

Comment: Also, for questions regarding "how can this be simplified/written better" a better site would be https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Sub CopyValues()

'Declare counter variables
Dim i As Integer, j as Integer, lastrow As Long
'Declare variables
Dim Sourcedataws As Worksheet, WStotransfer As Worksheet
'Declare sheet variables
Set Sourcedataws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Source Data")
Set WStotransferws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("WStotransfer")

lastrow = Sourcedataws.Cells(Sourcedataws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

WStotransferws.Range("C18:I18").ClearContents

For i = 2 To lastrow
    If WStotransferws.Range("I18").Value="" Then
        If Sourcedataws.Range("AA" & i).Value = "Condition" Then
            Sourcedataws.Range("A"&i).Copy 
            j=WStotransferws.Cells(18, WStotransferws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            WStotransferws.Cells(18,j+1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            End If
        Else
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```